# What does the suffix letter mean in the PRI column of "ps -M pid" under MacOS/X?

Tags: ps, threads

When I execute this command under MacOS/X:

```
ps -M 9358
```

I get this output:

```
USER   PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
jaf   9358 s009    0.0 S    31T   0:00.21   0:00.32 /Users/jaf/some-program
      9358         0.0 S    33T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
      9358        23.6 R    63R   0:01.13   1:18.74 
      9358        24.1 R    63R   0:02.86   1:20.32 
      9358         5.8 S    63R   0:00.91   0:21.53 
      9358        15.7 S    63R   0:00.56   1:02.22 
      9358         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
      9358         0.0 S    31T   0:00.09   0:00.11
```

My questions is about the values in the PRI column.  I understand that they are thread priorities (and that larger numbers mean higher-priority threads, I think), but what do the "T" and "R" suffixes indicate?  (I couldn't find any explanation of this in the "man ps" page)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the official Mac OS X `man` page for [`ps`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html), the suffix indicates the state of the process:

- `I`: Marks a process that is idle (sleeping for longer than about 20 seconds).
- `R`: Marks a runnable process.
- `S`: Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20  seconds.
- `T`: Marks a stopped process.
- `U`: Marks a process in uninterruptible wait.
- `Z`: Marks a dead process (a “zombie”).